# UI5 Web Components Select does not open

Tags: typescript, web-component, lit-html, ui5-webcomponents

I want to use the UI5 Web Component "Select" for my Site, but the dropdown doesn't open.

I'm using Lit-HTML, Typescript and Webpack.
I copied the example from the Playground into my code and imported both modules (Select, StandardListItem).
The exact example as well as my changed version doesn't work.
But it shows the li-Element with the Attribute `selected`.
I also use a few other UI5 Components, like Input or Datepicker, which works fine.

The Select Element:

```
<ui5-select class="select" id="sex">
    <ui5-li selected>Weiblich</ui5-li>
    <ui5-li>Männlich</ui5-li>
    <ui5-li>Andere</ui5-li>
</ui5-select>
```

And I imported:

```
import '@ui5/webcomponents/dist/Select';
import '@ui5/webcomponents/dist/StandardListItem';
```

I expected an dropdown menu, but nothing happens when I click on the little arrow or the field.

Comment: If you file an issue with the maker you will probably get a better answer: https://github.com/SAP/ui5-webcomponents/issues

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the UI5 Web components you are using?
With the latest version 1.0.0-rc.2 the ui5-select expects ui5-option(s), instead of ui5-li items.

```html
<ui5-select>
    <ui5-option icon="sap-icon://iphone">Phone</ui5-option>
    <ui5-option icon="sap-icon://ipad">Tablet</ui5-option>
    <ui5-option icon="sap-icon://laptop" selected>Desktop</ui5-option>
</ui5-select>
```

You can file an issue at: [github.com/SAP/ui5-webcomponents/issues](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-webcomponents/issues)
and perhaps you can provide a code snippet to look at.